# Set White.UIItems.TextBox.Text to unicode

Tags: c#, unicode, white-framework

I am launching one app for Korean-to-English translation in semi automatic way using "White framework". Then launching UI again by using White framework and creating text box and combo box to give input to UI in C# application.

While using this I am facing following problem.

I am not able to pass Korean text input to `TestStack.White.UIItems.TextBox.Text`. When I try to invoke the app through C# application. Each character is getting converted to `?`. May I know what can be the reason and if anyone of you used it in similar way please let me know or anyone of you have any suggestion which can help, then please let me know.

Comment: Is the string right before you pass it into the control?

Comment: When I assign Korean string to variable of type `TestStack.White.UIItems.TextBox.Text`, before passing to app, its getting converted to ? for each character.

Comment: You will get a better chance of seeing someone answer if you show the code. Usually question mark means that unicode character did not have a visual representation in current codepage.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TestStack.White.UIItems.TextBox.BulkText` property instead.

From the TestStack.White (ver. 0.13.3) documentation:

> **BulkText**: Sets the text in the textbox. The text would be cleared first. This is a better performing than the Text method. This doesn't raise all keyboard events. The string will be set **exactly** as it is in your code.